# PHP checkbox validation checked or not checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I've been using similar code to this for my project and I'm able to get all of the "Checked" checkboxes using the $_POST[]. However, I also need to get the value of the unchecked checkboxes since this form is dynamically being built and the number of checkboxes may vary as well as change state from checked to unchecked and vice versa.

```
<form method='post' action=''> <tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option One'>1<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>2<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>3
    </td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' class='buttons'> </form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvar'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['checkboxvar']); 
}
?>
```

I've seen some suggestions using **!isset($_POST[ ])** but I'm not certain on how that would work or if that is even a solution for the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes will not be passed into POST data.

Comment: If you don't mind using a little javascript, you can override the default submit behavior and build a json string with all the data you need then send that.

Comment: I'd rather tackle this with PHP if there is an option available to do that...

Comment: What does the java solution look like? Also, why does the $_POST array only contain those checkboxes that are "checked" and not all form objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a javascript as suggested by other users.

If you want to use only PHP and HTML you can use the following solution.
I write it, but I would not use this solution on a production environment.

```
<input type='hidden' name='checkboxvar[1]' value="0" />
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[1]' value='Option One' />1<br />
<input type='hidden' name='checkboxvar[2]' value="0" />
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[2]' value='Option Two' />2<br />
<input type='hidden' name='checkboxvar[3]' value="0" />
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[3]' value='Option Three' />3
```

In the $_POST array you should have something like that if Option One is selected.

```
Array
(
     [1] => Option One
     [2] => 0
     [3] => 0
)
```

Comment: Why does the $_POST contain hidden objects as in your example or is there another reason they appear in the $_POST???

Comment: hidden elements are always sent to POST in forms. Only disabled elements are not sent.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden